# Can't Detect User Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, roleprovider, login-control

Using asp.net and c# and visual studio 2010
I have a login page and a login control in it and i'm doing something that when a user try's to login , it will detect the user role. Here's my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Admin"] != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/HomeAdmin.aspx");
        }
        else if (Session["Professor"] != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Professor/HomeProfessor.aspx");
        }
        else if (Session["Student"] != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Student/HomeStudent.aspx");
        }            
    }

    protected void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administor"))
        {
            Session["Admin"] = Login1.UserName;
            //only run for admins
        }




        else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Professor"))
        {
            Session["Professor"] = Login1.UserName;
            //only run for professors
        }





        else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Student"))
        {
            Session["Student"] = Login1.UserName;
            //only run for students
        }
    }
}
```

Then when i login it will detect the wrong role for example i login with a Admin user but it will detect it as a Student!
And as you see in the code it will redirect me to the page (HomeStudent.aspx).

Here's a view of my role manager:[Click here to see the image of my role manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFy6K.png)

What do you think is the problem and what should i do?!!

Comment: Why don't you put the role in one `Session["Role"]` and assign a different value on each login. Then, on `Login1_LoggingIn` event you could first reset your Session with `Session.Clear()` ,then assign it to the new value

Comment: You mean making 3 login pages? (for each role one login page?)

Comment: No, not at all. Just the Session["Role"] will have three values, based on the role logged in, like this: `if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administor"))
        {
            Session["Role"] ="Administrator";
            //only run for admins
        }
 else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Professor"))
        {
            Session["Role"] = "Professor";
            //only run for professors
        }`
and then call the value of the Session, instead of checking if it's `null`. I have not checked at detail the code above, but probably this should work

Comment: I did what you said but i still have the problem. I think because the main problem is : when the compiler is reading the IF section

Comment: I did what you said but i still have the problem. I think it's because the main problem is from somewhere else : when the compiler is reading the IF section , this problem happens. As i said when it reads the if section it can't validate if the user is in for example admin role or not...

Comment: Just a question, this problem happened since the first time you tried to login, or just after you logged out as a Student and tried to log in as an Admin?

Comment: The first time that i login this problem happens

Comment: Where are the roles being stored? If you put a breakpoint in `if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administor"))
        {
            Session["Admin"] = Login1.UserName;
            //only run for admins
        }` after the first bracket, what is the value you see?

Comment: So, you close every instance of the code, every process that is accessing it, and when you run the code again, you have the same problem?

Comment: It's disordered sometimes when i login for the first time there is no problem and it does it right but second time it does it wrong AND  sometimes when i login for the first time  it does it wrong but second time it does it with no problem

Comment: Then, the problem should be with the logout function. After you logout a user, be sure to clear the Session, or it will save the last value it had

Comment: A question : when i run the project (start debugging the login page) and then i login and then i stop debugging and then again start debugging have i logged out the again logged in?

Comment: it depends. Sometimes, the process associated with the debugged project does not end, so it saves the last values of unclosed Sessions. However, do you have a logout function? How do you manage the logout?

Comment: I have a Login Status in each home page for each roles . in the event(logged out) of the login status i have wrote this : Session.Clear()

Comment: And you still have the problem?

Comment: yep when i login as an admin and then log out and then again i login but this time as an student i see a page with an error the error is this the resource cannot be found

Comment: Then, try to debug the program. Take it back at it's original state and see what values do you retrieve from the Sessions

Comment: How can i see what values do i retrieve from the Sessions?

Comment: first, put a breakpoint at the sessions, ore second option, instead of redirecting, put a `Response.Write(Session["Role"].ToString())` and see what it outputs at the page itself

Comment: When i do that , the compiler gives me this error: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Object reference not set to an instance of an object :::::: ////And it puts the error on the code yousaid.:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Comment: Wait a minute i think my problem is solved What i was wrong in was that i forget to put a (login1.username) before the user.isinrole!

Comment: Well, this explain the nullPointerException...OK, if that solved the problem, than post the solution as an answer and accept it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and solved my problem by changing codes to this :

```
 if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName , "Administor"))
    {
        Session["Admin"] = Login1.UserName;
        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/HomeAdmin.aspx");       
        //only run for admins

    }


    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName , "Professor"))
    {
        Session["Professor"] = Login1.UserName;
        Response.Redirect("~/Professor/HomeProfessor.aspx");
        //only run for professors
    }



    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName , "Student"))
    {
        Session["Student"] = Login1.UserName;
        Response.Redirect("~/Student/HomeStudent.aspx"); 
        //only run for students
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Event `LoggingIn` is fired when login form is posted, but before user is authenticated (check on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggingin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

You should check `Roles.IsUserInRole("yourRole")` on `LoggedIn` event rather then `LoggingIn`.

Comment: What i first did was the thing you said... But i still had this problem

Comment: If you run `Roles.GetRolesForUser() ` inside LoggedIn event, what does it return?

Comment: You mean just writing : Roles.GetRolesForUsers() in the logged in event or set it equal to something(For example a label)?

Comment: @mohammadtalaie still in that problem?

Comment: Yeah... still trying to fix it don't have anymore idea that may fix this problem?

Comment: @mohammadtalaie. Does your authentication work? If yes, check roles that you assigned to your users. Maybe you forgot to do that.

Comment: Well what i did was that i have created 3 roles in asp.net configuration (Website Administration tool) and the created 3 users and assigned them to desired roles and that's all ...